# Ignore ESC Special Character on XML Unmarshal Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, xml-parsing

I have a third party xml file that I can not change.
One of the fields in the XML has the ESC character in the middle of the field's value.
I want to add an unmarshal property that just ignores all ESC characters fields it finds.

Is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

This is my read stream that I use to unmarshal my custom class `TransactionType`. Also, the latter can not be changed.

```java
  @Bean
  public MultiResourceItemReader<TransactionType> customItemReader() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setCheckForXmlRootElement(false);
    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(TransactionType.class);
    marshaller.supports(TransactionType.class);

    StaxEventItemReader<TransactionType> posLogStaxEventItemReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
    posLogStaxEventItemReader.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    posLogStaxEventItemReader.setFragmentRootElementName("{http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/}Transaction");

    MultiResourceItemReader<TransactionType> transactionReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    transactionReader.setDelegate(posLogStaxEventItemReader);

    return transactionReader;
  }
```

I have lots of development restrictions that I can not ignore, so if this character ignoring is possible I can only do it when creating the unmarshaller.

Right now the unmarshal breaks because `<ID><![CDATA[888711173110]]></ID>` has the invalid characters. I want to ignore it as if the CDATA block contained `888711173110`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I wanted by reading the file as bytes, convert it to string, remove the unwanted characters with `.replace()`, convert it back to bytes, convert it to input stream.

Not elegant solution but it worked.

The unmarshaller already expects a well constructed XML, for that reason I could not achieve what I wanted during the file reading.